# how to print the lightbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the some text loaded in light box with background faded.

i want the print button in the light box so that when user click on that only the contents of light box is printed and printer box opens up.

How to do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a print stylesheet?

Basically when it prints use a css stylesheet to hide everything that is not in the lightbox.

[CSS Design: Going to Print](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)

Comment: It measn that in lightbox i had print button with javascript

href="javascript:window.print();";

and i use style sheet print.css
#wholeWrapper{
display:none
}

Will that work

Answer (score 1):

When you open up your lightbox you want to add a print stylesheet that hides everything else but what is in the lightbox.  When you close the lightbox remove that stylesheet.